# Are breakers directional?

Tags: electrical

I am installing a breaker/overcurrent protection device and I have realised I don't know if it matters which terminal sees the incoming phase wire, and which one is for the output.

The device is ABB S201-B16 (16 A/230 V).

Comment: Is this a DIN rail breaker, or...? Also, does it have any special functions? (AFCI/GFCI/....)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, it's a DIN rail mounted breaker, no special functions, only short circuit and delayed overcurrent (electromechanical and thermal), according to the [ABB site](http://www.abb.com/product/seitp329/49a79353b0194401c12572ab00257544.aspx?tabKey=2&gid=ABB2CDS251001R1165).

Comment: ...and this is a case where we actually need an Euro-electrical expert -- I know that in NEC-land it depends on whether there are line/load markings on the breaker or not, but I have no clue if they follow the same convention across the pond.